# Wrong sorting results with spacial index in Raven DB

Tags: sorting, indexing, ravendb, spatial-query

When I try to take the 10 latest results (oder by date desc) from my index, I receive old documents. It look like the query take 10 outdated items and sort it. I have this problem when the query have many results to play with.

Here's my index definition:

```
public class Home_ByCategoryTagAndLocation : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Home>
{
    public Home_ByCategoryTagAndLocation()
    {
        Map = home => from n in home                          
            from t in n.Source.CategoryTag
            from c in n.Locations
            select new { CategoryTag = t, n.DatePublished, _ = SpatialIndex.Generate(c.Latitude, c.Longitude) };
    }
}
```

I call my index using this code:

```
public static List<Home> GetLatestHomeNear(IDocumentStore store, CityLocation location, int maxResults = 15)
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Home>("Home/ByCategoryTagAndLocation")                            
                .WithinRadiusOf(radius: location.DefaultRadius, latitude: location.Latitude, longitude: location.Longitude)
                .OrderByDescending(n => n.DatePublished)
                .Take(maxResults)
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    return new List<Home>();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post appears to be describing the normal behavior of [stale indexes](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/stale-indexes).

This is not related at all to spatial indexes.  That just happens to be the index that is stale.